# Does it really make sense to talk about field lines?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, normalization

[Field lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line) should only provide a visual representation of a field.
There is a rule for their construction: take an object subject to a field, move it by d$\mathbf{r}$ and draw the direction of the force due to the field. 
Do it indefinitely, connect all the d$\mathbf{r}$ and get a line. A *field line*.

Some examples of common 'properties' of field lines:

The density of field lines is related to the strength of a field.

In plasma physics, there is an effect called *flux freezing*, where the number of field lines crossing a contour stays constant under topological changes of the contour.

**BUT**  field lines do not occupy a physical position in space so we can draw how many we want?

Does it make sense, then, to talk about the **number** of field lines?

Comment: While I discourage people from talking about "field lines" because I see students confuse themselves that way, the construct can be made mathematically equivalent to a vector field that is divergenceless except at charges. So this becomes a questions about pedagogy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense to talk about the **number** of field lines, but only if you take care to represent the field *amplitude* as being *inversely proportional to the spacing between the lines*.  With that, the total number of lines crossing a surface is proportional to the flux, etc.

Some people, notably textbook authors [Chabay and Sherwood](http://matterandinteractions.org/), feel that the field line concept causes more problems than it solves.  (They do agree that the concept is useful in plasma physics.) I don't happen to agree with them, personally.